# How can I split my sheet with 3 different dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr

[See the sample data: Link](http://cfile5.uf.tistory.com/image/2627AE4E558BDCCE1FADDC)

I would like to split my data above up 3 different data following the rule below.

1. Only have 'AID' (10 String starting with "OA")
2. Only have 'CID' (14 numeric)
3. Have nothing ('-', NA and etc)

I tried to use `dplyr` but couldn't find a right solution.

Comment: sry but just read a basic R-tutorial for selecting and filtering columns of data-frames, there are a gazillion resources for this, specifically if you want to use dplyr read this: http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## change column as char

`as.character(data3$AID)
as.character(data3$CID)`

## Use dplyr filter

`library(dplyr)
Q1 <- data3 %>% filter(nchar(data3$AID) >= 10) 
Q2 <- data3 %>% filter(nchar(data3$CID) >= 14)
Q3 <- data3 %>% filter(nchar(data3$AID) < 10 & nchar(data3$CID) < 14)`

Okay, I'm done